# reference modification move on comp-3 assumed decimal type variable in cobol

Tags: cobol

how to perform reference modification move on comp-3 assumed decimal type variable in cobol.
I have the following variables in ws section

```
01 num1 s9(7)v9(2) comp-3 value 5489.00

02 num2 9(12)
```

I need to store the value of num1 into num2 as 000000548900.

Comment: Reference modification is for USAGE DISPLAY variables.

Comment: @thulasi-hari: I guess one of the two answers helped, didn't it? If yes please mark an answer as solution...

Answer (score 5):

Don't use reference modification. Use:

```
multiply num1 by 100 giving num2
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the `PICTURE` of `num2` to `PIC 9(10)V99`.